# Why does python treat asterisk differently in functions and expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In the following codes there are two places which asterisk(*) is used :

**Asterisk in function:**

```
def function(*asterisk):
    print(1, type(asterisk))
```

**Asterisk in expressions:**

```
a, *b = (1, 2, 3)
print(2, type(b))

a, *b = [1, 2, 3]
print(3, type(b))
```

I know the meaning of asterisk in functions and how it works.

My question is why asterisk in print number 1 has a **tuple** type whereas in print number 2 and 3 has a **list** type ?

Why python interprets function *parameter as **tuple** regardless of argument's type and interprets *variable as **list** regardless of assigned numbers' type in expressions?

In the end, are those * different operators?!

Comment: Those asterisks aren't operators at all. They're just part of the syntax.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  Yes,my fault, I thought I can call it asterisk operator because I saw it be called an operator in [from XXX import *]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devs just figured a list would be easier to process in the assignment case. Quoting the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for `a, *b = ...` syntax:

> After a short discussion on the python-3000 list [[1]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#id3), the PEP was accepted by Guido in its current form. Possible changes discussed were:
>
> - ...
> - Make the starred target a tuple instead of a list. This would be consistent with a function's *args, but make further processing of the result harder.

And the [mailing list discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007300.html):

> IMO, it's likely that you would like to further process the resulting
> sequence, including modifying it.

The mailing list discussion is pretty short ([starts here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007198.html), only 28 messages), so don't be afraid to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

The unpacking in assignment (python 3 specific) is [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) (when the unpacking term refers to the *right hand side*, the variable that follows `*` in the left hand side isn't unpacked, but *created*), whereas the other one (also available in python 2) is just positional argument unpacking.

The `*` "operator" is very different in both cases. The fact that extended iterable unpacking creates a `list` is probably designed so the caller can *extend* that list.

In parameter unpacking, it's better to have a fixed iterable like `tuple`. Once again those are completely different mechanisms.